# QMovie webp frame stutters

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, webp

I'm using QMovie to play a webp animation on a QLabal, the code like:

```
Foo::Foo() {
    movie_ = new QMovie("/path/to/my.webp", "", this);
    ui->label->setMovie(movie_);
}
void Foo::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    movie_->stop();
    movie_->start();
}
```

But when I play the animation, the frame stutters, like:

[image: the screenshot]

I try to extract the webp frames by using QImage::save, the code like:

```
QImageReader *reader = new QImageReader("/path/to/my.webp");
reader->setDecideFormatFromContent(true);
for (int i = 0; i < reader->imageCount(); ++i) {
    QImage image;
    reader->read(&image);
    image.save(QString("frame_%1.png").arg(i));
    reader->jumpToNextImage();
}
```

all the extracted frames are stutters too, like:

[image: frame_9.png]

But when I extract frames by using google libwebp tool, there is no any problem.like:

[image: frame_9_2.png]

```
// extract frame 9, not problem
webpmux.exe -get frame 9  -o "frame_9.webp"
// paly webp animation, there is no any problem
vwebp.exe /path/to/my.webp
```

Is it a Qt problem? both Qt 5.9.4(i'm using) and Qt latest version(i'm trying) has this problem.

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, here it's my webp file link.
`https://github.com/scjhan/webp_demo/blob/master/cheers.webp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a Qt bug, the bug has reported on Qt version 5.9.1:
[WebP: animations don't respect alpha](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61640)

Qt said the bug was solved on version 5.9.2, but the problems still exist even Qt 5.11.

there is the offical [solution](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtimageformats.git/diff/src/plugins/imageformats/webp/qwebphandler.cpp?id=144a3535db9f95e60972d3c3b6eaceb65a604577):

```
diff --git a/src/plugins/imageformats/webp/qwebphandler.cpp b/src/plugins/imageformats/webp/qwebphandler.cpp
index 5a0ae4a..ce90158 100644
--- a/src/plugins/imageformats/webp/qwebphandler.cpp
+++ b/src/plugins/imageformats/webp/qwebphandler.cpp
@@ -122,6 +122,8 @@ bool QWebpHandler::ensureScanned() const
                 that->m_bgColor = QColor::fromRgba(QRgb(WebPDemuxGetI(m_demuxer, WEBP_FF_BACKGROUND_COLOR)));

                 that->m_composited = new QImage(that->m_features.width, that->m_features.height, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
+                if (that->m_features.has_alpha)
+                    that->m_composited->fill(Qt::transparent);

                 // We do not reset device position since we have read in all data
                 m_scanState = ScanSuccess;
@@ -193,6 +195,8 @@ bool QWebpHandler::read(QImage *image)
     } else {
         // Animation
         QPainter painter(m_composited);
+        if (m_features.has_alpha && m_iter.dispose_method == WEBP_MUX_DISPOSE_BACKGROUND)
+            m_composited->fill(Qt::transparent);
         painter.drawImage(currentImageRect(), frame);

         *image = *m_composited;
```

Here is my solution:

1.add some code

```
// ${QT_SRC}/qtimageformats/src/plugins/imageformats/webp/qwebphandler.cpp
// function QWebpHandler::read
if (m_features.has_alpha && (m_iter.dispose_method == WEBP_MUX_DISPOSE_BACKGROUND || 
            m_iter.blend_method == WEBP_MUX_NO_BLEND)) {
      m_composited->fill(Qt::transparent);
}
```

2. rebuild qt webp plugin

`nmake module-qtimageformats`

3. replace qwebp.dll

`mv ${QT_DIR}/plugins/imageformats/qwebpd.dll ${QT_DIR}/plugins/imageformats/qwebpd.dll.bak`

`cp ${REBUILD_WEBP_PLUGINS} ${QT_DIR}/plugins/imageformats/qwebpd.dll`